# Erro na hora de instalar o composer

Tags: php, cmd, composer, autoload

Olá, estou com um problema na hora de instalar o composer pelo cmd. Alguém poderia me ajudar, por favor? Ocorre esse erro aqui:

```
 "./composer.json" does not match the expected JSON schema:- name : Does not match the regex pattern ^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?
```

Esse é o meu composer json.

```
{
"name": "miniframewrok",
"require": {
    "php": ">=8.0"

},
"authors": [
    {"name": "samuel"}

  ],
"autoload": {
    "psr-4":{
        "App\\": "App/",
        "MF\\": "vendor/MF/"
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este erro ocorre pois o atual formato do seu Package name está incorreto, deve ser dessa forma: `(<vendor>/<name>)`.

Poderia usar por exemplo: "name": framewrok/seunome".

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado! Deu certo.

Comment: Que bom lhe ajudei.  por favor marcar a pergunta como resolvido.